# Deploy WCF service in the windows service and use in the web application

Tags: wcf

in my web application, I wanted to use the wcf service hosted as a windows service.
i dont know how to achive this ?

can you please provide me some links or example to do this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good approach IMO. Web applications should be sandboxed within the browser and should not access system resources in any manner. You might want to make a wrapper WCF Web Service which will called by the windows service and your web app can then access the Web Service.

For the sake of answering the problem:
[**Original Link for Code**](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/community/aspnet/2/16846/accessing-windows-service-thru-web-application.aspx):

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
string PcName = "PC Name"; 
            WindowsImpersonationContext wic = null; 

            try 
            { 

                IPrincipal p = this.User; 

                WindowsIdentity id = (WindowsIdentity)p.Identity; 

                Response.Write("Running as:" +  WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name + "<br>"); 

                wic = id.Impersonate(); 

                Response.Write("Running as:" +  WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name + "<br>"); 

                ServiceController[] services = ServiceController.GetServices(); 

                for(int i = 0; i <  services.Length; i++) 
                { 

                    if (services[i].DisplayName == "COM+ System Application") 
                    { 
                        Response.Write(services[i].DisplayName + " - "); 
                        Response.Write(services[i].Status.ToString()); 
                        Response.Write("<br>"); 
                        ServiceController sc = new ServiceController(services[i].DisplayName,PcName); 

                        if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Running) 
                        { 
                            sc.Stop(); 
                        } 
                        if (sc.Status == ServiceControllerStatus.Stopped) 
                        { 
                            sc.Start(); 
                        } 

                    } 
                } 
            }   
            catch(Exception err ) 
            { 
                Response.Write(err.Message); 
            }         
            finally 
            { 
                wic.Undo(); 
            } 

        }
```

But you might run into security issues, so take a look at all the responses in the thread.